# Unable to update Pandas dataframe element with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas dataframe where its just 2 columns: the first being a name, and the second being a dictionary of information relevant to the name. Adding new rows works fine, but if I try to updates the dictionary column by assigning a new dictionary in place, I get

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

So, to be exact, this is what I was doing to produce the error:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', {'b':1}]], columns=['name', 'attributes'])
pos = df[df.loc[:,'name']=='a'].index[0]
df.loc[pos, 'attributes'] = {'c':2}
```

I was able to find another solution that seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', {'b':1}]], columns=['name', 'attributes'])
pos = df[df.loc[:,'name']=='a'].index[0]
df.loc[:,'attributes'].at[pos] = {'c':2}
```

but I was hoping to get an answer as to why the first method doesn't work, or if there was something wrong with how I had it initially.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to access a dataframe with an index 'pos', you have to use iloc to access the row. So changing your last row as following would work as intended:

```
df.iloc[pos]['attributes'] = {'c':2}
```

Comment: `.loc` works for accessing the row since the indices are numbered the same as their positions. so `.loc` and `.iloc` function the same. Doing your snippet with `.loc` seems to works as well though

Answer (score 0):

For me working [`DataFrame.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
df.at[pos, 'attributes'] = {'c':2}
print (df)
  name attributes
0    a   {'c': 2}
```